# Magento Global Messages on CMS pages

Tags: magento, content-management-system, global, message

I'm curious if anyone knows how to move the global messages inside the content on CMS pages. The problem is that I've set up some newsletter signup static blocks, but after firing, the global messages pushes the content down and mildly breaks the layout by pushing the white text of the page title off the green background image and over a light grey background, making it difficult to read.

Just thinking if this can be moved about in the XML so that it comes *after* the page-title, instead of before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to move this block around.

The messages section is inside of phtml, and you should just make a div inside your page-title.  **You need to do this with customer/session as you are using static blocks.**

```
<div id="messages_product_view">
<?php Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>
<?php echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I dropped that into /template/cms/content_heading.phml but it's not appearing. I tried 'core/session' as well, same thing. Thinking there was something silly going on with the XML, I commented the default block out of 1-column.phtml and placed it in the appropriate spot inside cms.xml and again, not showing. Is this a case of the block being dispatched but never rendered, and the message subsequently destroyed?

Comment: This block doesn't need to be in xml.  This is ONLY in the .phtml files.  You can move the commented out section into a <div> that would integrate it into the design.  The block isn't dispatched for rendering if it isn't in xml, xml controls everything that the database doesn't, and if it is in the database the database wins.  check app/design/frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml as a reference for how messages are shown.

Comment: how i can identify message like success/error/notice ?

Comment: This may be able to help you.  http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40324/